# Nested-If statements in Shell-scripting

Tags: shell, unix, nested-if

This is my script:

```
echo "Name"

read name

if [ "$name" == "abcd" ]; then

 echo "Password"

 read password

 if [ "$password == "pwd" ]; then

  echo "Hello"

 else

  echo "Wrong password"

 fi

else

 echo "wrong username"

fi
```

And this is the output I get when I run it:

```
sh hello.sh

Name

abcd

hello.sh: line 14: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

hello.sh: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Any idea whats wrong here? This could be a very silly one, but i wasted almost an hour on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if [ "$password == "pwd" ]; then
```

You have an unmatched `"` before `$password`

Answer (score 3):

you can use `case`. Here's an example. You won't want to tell anybody which component is wrong, for security reason.

```
echo "Name"
read name
echo "Password"
read password
case "${name}${password}" in
 "abcdpwd" ) 
     echo "hello";;
  *) echo "User or password is wrong";;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

In Shell script.

```
if condition
    then
        if condition
        then
            .....
            ..
            do this
        else
            ....
            ..
            do this
        fi
    else
        ...
        .....
        do this
    fi
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if [ "$name" == "abcd" ];
then
  echo "Password"
  read password
  if [ "$password" == "pwd" ];
  then
    echo "Hello"
  else
    echo "Wrong password"
  fi
else
  echo "wrong username"
fi
```

Comment: Please, format your code and add short explanation.