# The `continue` inside `if condition` is not going to next lines of the script

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, if-statement

I have a bash script with an `if condition` and continuous lines of script. However, after `if condition` nothing in the script seems to run. For example, here are the lines of script (The lines after `continue` in `if condition` are not reacting).

```
 dir=/usr/path/tofiles
    for file in $(find $dir -name \*txt)
    do
        fbase={file%.txt}
        if [ "$step" == "1" -a ! -f "${fbase}.header" ]
            then
                continue
        fi

    ### From here nothing in the script runs #####

        if [ -f "${fbase}merged" ]
        then
                echo "$file already merged"
        fi

       files="$files ${fbase}g.txt.gz"
       cnt=$(($cnt + 1))
       if [ "$cnt" -eq "$chunksize" ]
       then
           outid=$(uuidgen)
           logfile=${outdir}/${outid}.cluster.log
           echo "sh $(pwd)/mysecript.sh $outid $files"  
       fi
    done
```

After the first `if condition` nothing in the script is running,  I tried printing using `echo` nothing is showing up. Precisely, the issue is after the `continue` statement within the `if condition`. Any help/suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanking you

Comment: In case your first `if statement` is always `true` you'll always skip the rest of the loop (due to `continue`), so nothing else will be executed.

Comment: I added a link with the infos you need. The official `bash` guide.

Comment: From your comments at the other post, I'd like to tell you that it is also possible to use the `if statement` to check if some criteria is not true. You do it like `if [ ! condition ] `. So what you normally have in your `else` case implicitly, that the condition is not fulfilled, can be put as condition into the `if`. `!`means logical `NOT`.

Comment: That's what I am doing in my if statement checking certain conditions using `IF NOT` (!) and `AND` (`-a`). My question is, after that condition the script is not jumping to next ` if-statement`.  The  `continue`  within the `if-statement` is not functioning as it required to.

Comment: Ok, so you need to nest your `if`s, which means that you go to the next statement if the first is `true`. Is this what you want?

Comment: yes, but when i nest the `if's`  then I will not get what I want. Else, what you asked is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a wrong interpretation of the `continue` statements.

The `continue` statement skips the lines below it and starts with the next iteration.

```
while (true) {
  print(1);
  if (true) {
    continue;
  }
  print(2);
}
```

In the above `print(2)` will never get executed as it skips it everytime and starts with the next iteration.

For deeper insight please read [Nested-If statements in Shell-scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726839/nested-if-statements-in-shell-scripting)

For your scenario please try this

```
dir=/usr/path/tofiles
    for file in $(find $dir -name \*txt)
    do
        fbase={file%.txt}
        if ! [ "$step" == "1" -a ! -f "${fbase}.header" ]
        then
            if [ -f "${fbase}merged" ]
            then
                echo "$file already merged"
            fi

            files="$files ${fbase}g.txt.gz"
            cnt=$(($cnt + 1))
            if [ "$cnt" -eq "$chunksize" ]
            then
                outid=$(uuidgen)
                logfile=${outdir}/${outid}.cluster.log
                echo "sh $(pwd)/mysecript.sh $outid $files"  
            fi
        fi
    done
```

Comment: In this case, I need to go to the next `if loop` after the first one. How is it possible.Thanks

Comment: @user1017373 You can use `if elseif` statements, so in case the first `if` is not true, it starts evaluating next `elseif` condition

Comment: The script is bash shell. **This is not written in python**.

Comment: @user1017373 oh, my bad dude. Use this link please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726839/nested-if-statements-in-shell-scripting

Comment: @user1017373 I've edited my answer, please mark it as correct answer if you think it has guided you to the correct direction

Comment: Ok, let me be more clear, I have an `if statement` to check all files, and if the files are not falling in the condition mentioned then I need my script go to next  `if statement`, therefore I used `continue` (as it jumps into next iteration). I do not have any `else statement` within the same `if statement`. Hence, it should go to next `if statement ` and so on. However, this is not happening after the `continue`.

Comment: @user1017373 i've edited my answer for your use, please have a look

Comment: Ok, Thanks I do not want the second  `if loop` within the first. That is not the case here. The script is I posted is part of a longer shell script. This nested loop will not suit my requrement. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your script is, that in case your first `if` statement evaluates always to true you'll always skip the rest of the loop, due to the `continue`, so nothing else will be executed. This behavior is the same as in all other programming languages.

- `continue`, like `break`, is a keyword to control the loop behavior. This means that using `continue`it is possible to skip the rest of the current loop iteration. And using `break` it is possible to exit the loop.

In case you need to go further to the next `if statement`, you need to nest your `if`s, so that both are checked/evaluated.

More background information regarding this issue can be found [here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loopcontrol.html).

According to your comments, your code should include nested `if`s, like:

```sh
dir=/usr/path/tofiles
  for file in $(find $dir -name \*txt)
  do
    fbase={file%.txt}

    if [ "$step" == "1" -a ! -f "${fbase}.header" ]
    then
      if [ -f "${fbase}merged" ]
      then
        echo "$file already merged"
      fi

      files="$files ${fbase}g.txt.gz"
      cnt=$(($cnt + 1))
      if [ "$cnt" -eq "$chunksize" ]
      then
        outid=$(uuidgen)
        logfile=${outdir}/${outid}.cluster.log
        echo "sh $(pwd)/mysecript.sh $outid $files"  
      fi
    fi
done
```